# GCDWebServer always aborts on options check

Tags: ios, gcdwebserver

I started using GCDWebServer version 3.1 in an app last year, and this line in the `addHandlerWithMatchBlock` method of `GCDWebServer.m` always caused the system to abort immediately:

```
GWS_DCHECK(_options == nil);
```

I ended up just changing it to this to avoid the problem:

```
GWS_DCHECK(_options != nil);
```

Now I'm updating to the latest version 3.3.2 and see the same problem. My hack still works here, but I would like to know what a real solution would be. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See docs in header:

> Addling handlers while the server is running is not allowed.

Attempting to do this will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: Okay, I was initializing the server instance, then starting it, then adding handlers. It sounds like I need to initializing it, then add handlers, then start it. Thanks.