# Flutter Spotify iOS | MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listen on channel player_context_subscription)

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, spotify, flutter-method-channel

I am using a free Spotify account for development purposes only. I am trying to use this to connect my Flutter iOS application with Spotify. One thing to mention in advance is that the whole code I did is working fine on Android perfectly but not on iPhone. I followed the instructions in the section Setup the iOS SDK of [Spotify iOS SDK Quick Start](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/ios/quick-start/).  It connects then returns a token and opens my application and songs start playing on Spotify. I am able to hit the button at the bottom and it also changes the song "I'll Make a Man Out of You" which is linked in the example at https://github.com/brim-borium/spotify_sdk/tree/main/example

Well I just copied example project files in my project and use my ClientID and RedirectURL and it works well in Andriod but when I run it on iOS it started giving me the below error...

```
AppRemote: Connecting...
[connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C1.1.1:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
AppRemote: Established a connection to the Spotify app.
AppRemote: Authenticated with the Spotify app.
AppRemote: Established a session with the Spotify app.
flutter: \^[[38;5;12m┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;12m│ #0   _SpotifyExampleState.setStatus (package:runwith/screens/SpotifyExample/Debugging.dart:647:13)<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;12m│ #1   _SpotifyExampleState.getAccessToken (package:runwith/screens/SpotifyExample/Debugging.dart:459:7)<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;12m├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;12m│ 22:26:44.966 (+0:01:30.499038)<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;12m├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;12m│  Got a token: BQDPjhNCDTPalqK71CNYU2PGI_VF8ejg7PzaQK7e01p2mnpi4smf7bX5SCANXUd211T84grf_DgcKKmuWN7KbOGPy-sKESYmgKG59_4EC0MKX21E6mZ9UVPaH58D4ovtKg33DJRU9FRJEWODFOISYGIUU09S328EWEYYWR802384WUDJUF98YCOIFIHSDJHCJ38EYIEDN90WEUF0UJDOFCJW09R0JFOIJU0R9U0rlumS_GSMx-OR0arQdE7ayy-OJxIDXCyPIZ8o0NlQtQdPwoJ7ZIxT4vzmNj4kj4JnbWxiy2V5v6NdMhUY8qYLk7YmZSdY2oL8CZe9oMOGQSoXR7cJA<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;12m└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────<…>

======== Exception caught by services library ======================================================
The following MissingPluginException was thrown while activating platform stream on channel player_state_subscription:
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listen on channel player_state_subscription)

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:313:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      EventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:662:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by services library ======================================================
The following MissingPluginException was thrown while activating platform stream on channel player_context_subscription:
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listen on channel player_context_subscription)

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:313:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      EventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:662:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
====================================================================================================
```

So my main bug is `MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listen on channel player_state_subscription)` & `MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listen on channel player_context_subscription)`  that was not showing earlier and crashing the app in iOS then I did this [GCDWebServer always aborts on options check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37195995/gcdwebserver-always-aborts-on-options-check) then I am able to see upper error code.

Here is the rest of the required details...

**Other Plugin**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  # ThirdParty Dependencies Added Manually
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1
  http: ^0.13.4
  http_interceptor: ^1.0.2
  dio: ^4.0.4
  retrofit: ^3.0.0
  flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.5.1
  intl: ^0.17.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.9
  sn_progress_dialog: ^1.1.3
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.14
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.10.0
  animated_splash_screen: ^1.3.0
  country_code_picker: ^2.0.2
  country_codes: ^2.2.0
  animated_bottom_navigation_bar: ^1.1.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.1.1
  csc_picker: ^0.2.6
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.0
  location: ^4.4.0
  permission_handler: ^9.2.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.8
  provider: ^6.0.1
  flutter_polyline_points: 1.0.0
  share_plus: ^4.0.4
  flutter_background_service: ^2.4.5
  device_info_plus: ^8.0.0
  sensors_plus: ^2.0.1
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+8
  better_player: any
  flutter_google_places: 0.3.0
  google_maps_webservice: ^0.0.19
  google_api_headers: ^1.5.0
  custom_marker: 1.0.0
  pull_to_refresh: ^2.0.0
  spotify_sdk: ^2.3.1
  flutter_dotenv: ^5.0.2
  cast: ^1.1.1
  logger: ^1.1.0
  flutter_vlc_player: ^7.1.4
  app_settings: ^4.1.1
  number_to_words: ^1.0.0
  just_audio: ^0.9.31
  webview_flutter: ^3.0.4
  flutter_easyloading: ^3.0.5
  flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.6
  just_the_tooltip: ^0.0.12
  image: ^3.3.0
  screenshot: ^1.3.0
```

**Fluter Doctor**

```
/Users/my_macbook_username/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_v3.7.11/bin/flutter doctor --verbose
[!] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.11, on macOS 13.3.1 22E261 darwin-arm64, locale en-PK)
    • Flutter version 3.7.11 on channel stable at /Users/my_macbook_username/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_v3.7.11
    ! The flutter binary is not on your path. Consider adding /Users/my_macbook_username/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_v3.7.11/bin to your path.
    ! The dart binary is not on your path. Consider adding /Users/my_macbook_username/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_v3.7.11/bin to your path.
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision f72efea43c (3 weeks ago), 2023-04-11 11:57:21 -0700
    • Engine revision 1a65d409c7
    • Dart version 2.19.6
    • DevTools version 2.20.1
    • If those were intentional, you can disregard the above warnings; however it is recommended to use "git" directly to perform update checks and upgrades.

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/exeideasmy_macbook_usernameLibrary/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E222b
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • SM A325F (mobile) • RF8R509QMYF • android-arm64  • Android 13 (API 33)
    • macOS (desktop)   • macos       • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.3.1 22E261 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome      • web-javascript • Google Chrome 112.0.5615.137

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Target Platform, Version & Device**

- OS & Version: [iOS 16.1, Android 13]
- Device: [iPhone X, Samsung A32]

**Development OS**

- OS: [Mac OS 13.3.1 (22E261)]
- Android Studio [Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1]

## *UPDATE:*

After trying multiple ways, I found out that "flutter_background_service" plugin is breaking this Spotify Player State Stream. When I stop background service then it is working fine but when I start background service before the Spotify connection then it is giving me this error. Now how to keep both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, with the support of the Plugin Author, this bug is fixed and released in the new version of the plugin. You can read more history at https://github.com/brim-borium/spotify_sdk/issues/189

A new version has been released and can be used from pub.dev: https://pub.dev/packages/spotify_sdk/versions/3.0.0-dev.3